# How to return top n biggest cluster in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

in my database, the graph looks somehow like this:

[image: cluster]

I want to find the top 3 biggest cluster in my data. A cluster is a collection of nodes connected to each other, the direction of the connection is not important. As can be seen from the picture, the expected result should have 3 clusters with size 3 2 2 respectively.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n, size((n)-[*]-()) AS cluster_size
ORDER BY cluster_size  DESC
LIMIT 100
```

However, it has 2 problems:

1. I think the query is wrong because the [size()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-size-of-pattern-expression) function does not return the number of nodes in a cluster as I want, but the number of sub-graph matching the pattern instead.
2. The `LIMIT` clause limits the number of nodes to return, not taking the top result. That's why I put 100 there.

What should I do now? I'm stuck :( Thank you for your help.

---

### UPDATE

Thanks to [Bruno Peres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6835358/bruno-peres)' answer, I'm able to try `algo.unionFind` query in [Neo4j Graph Algorithm](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_community_detection_connected_components). I can find the size of my connected components using this query:

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream()
YIELD nodeId,setId
RETURN setId,count(*) as size_of_component
ORDER BY size_of_component DESC LIMIT 20;
```

And here is the result:
[image: Connected Components]

But that's all I know. I cannot get any information about the nodes in each component to visualize them. The `collect(nodeId)` takes forever because the top 2 components are too large. And I know it doesn't make sense to visualize those large components, but how about the third one? 235 nodes are fine to render.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Connected Componentes](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_community_detection_connected_components). The section about connected components of Neo4j Graph Algorithms User Guide says:

> **Connected Components** or UnionFind basically finds **sets of connected
>   nodes where each node is reachable from any other node in the same
>   set**. In graph theory, a connected component of an undirected graph is
>   a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by
>   paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the graph.

If this is your case you can [install Neo4j Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/#_installation) and use `algo.unionFind`. I reproduced your scenario with this sample data set:

```
create (x), (y),
(a), (b), (c),
(d), (e),
(f), (g),
(a)-[:type]->(b), (b)-[:type]->(c), (c)-[:type]->(a),
(d)-[:type]->(e),
(f)-[:type]->(g)
```

Then running `algo.unionFind`:

```
// call unionFind procedure
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('', ':type', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId
// groupBy setId, storing all node ids of the same set id into a list
WITH setId, collect(nodeId) as nodes
// order by the size of nodes list descending
ORDER BY size(nodes) DESC
LIMIT 3 // limiting to 3
RETURN setId, nodes
```

The result will be:

```
╒═══════╤══════════╕
│"setId"│"nodes"   │
╞═══════╪══════════╡
│2      │[11,12,13]│
├───────┼──────────┤
│5      │[14,15]   │
├───────┼──────────┤
│7      │[16,17]   │
└───────┴──────────┘
```

---

**EDIT**

From comments:

> how can I get all nodeId of a specific setId? For example, from my
>   screenshot above, how can I get all nodeId of the setId 17506? That
>   setId has 235 nodes and I want to visualize them.

1. Run call `CALL algo.unionFind('', ':type', {write:true, partitionProperty:"partition"}) YIELD nodes RETURN *. This statement will create a`partition` property for each node, containing the partition ID the node is part of.
2. Run this statement to get the top 3 partitions: `match (node)
   with node.partition as partition, count(node) as ct order by ct desc
   limit 3 return partition, ct`.
3. Now you can get all nodes of each top 3 partitions individually with `match (node {partition : 17506}) return node`, using the partition ID returned in the second query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very helpful. Sorry for my late reply because I didn't have any chance to test it. I will let you know as soon as possible :)

Comment: I tried your query with a small modification. I use `algo.unionFind.stream()` because I don't care about the node label or relationship type. However, the query took so long that I could not get the result. My database has around 860k nodes and 2.5 million relationships. Is it too big for that kind of query? :(

Comment: I think the `collect(nodeId)` freezes the query because as I inspected, the largest component has around 833k nodes.

Comment: Hello @AnhTriet. Yes, maybe `collect` is degrading your query performance. Have you tried removing `collect` to check performance?

Comment: Yes, without `collect`, it works fine. Please check my edited question :)

Comment: @AnhTriet Maybe you can use `algo.unionFind` instead of `algo.unionFind.stream`.  This way you can specify a property name to store the partition id in each node. Then you can query your dataset to visualize the partitions by id.

Comment: @AnhTriet something like `CALL algo.unionFind('', ':type', {write:true, partitionProperty:"partition"})
YIELD nodes
RETURN *`. Then you can query the dataset using `match(:Node {partition : 1000}) return node`. Maybe a index for partition property can improve performance. @AnhTriet

Comment: Is there any way to get all (or at least 1) `nodeId` from a `setId`?

Comment: @AnhTriet sorry, I did not understand. Can you explain with more details? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: how can I get all `nodeId` of a specific `setId`? For example, from my screenshot above, how can I get all `nodeId` of the `setId` 17506? That `setId` has 235 nodes and I want to visualize them.

Comment: Hi @AnhTriet, sorry for my late answer. I updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Hi @Bruno, yes, thank you so much for your helpful support! :)

Comment: How can I return node labels, instead of nodeIds? Each node has one label.